# I can't put external javascript inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got some pretty simple HTML, a photo and some text but I want to put a javascript element between them. This element is a countdown timer and can be inserted using external javascript.

I have a codepen with the HTML, inline css, and javascript here: https://codepen.io/thomaskwelker/pen/xjwQPj

```
<div class="kanye-wrapper">
  <div class="kanye-photo">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/star-clan/images/9/90/Kanye.png">
  </div>
  <div class="kanye-timer">
    <script src="js/kanye.js"></script>
  </div>
  <div class="kanye-link">
    <a href="https://google.com">See why</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've done hours of Googling and trying things. Could some please tell me how I can get the javascript timer inside the "kanye-timer" div?

Comment: Please provide a better explanation why what is shown is not working and how you have determined it isn't working. Take a few minutes to thoroughly read [ask]

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you hope to achieve? What exactly doesn't work? Are errors reported?

Comment: Just because you place your script inside a div doesn't mean that is where any appended elements are going to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$(document.body).append($r.cvs);`, try `$('.kanye-timer').append($r.cvs);`

This tells the JS to append the timer to the div, rather that just placing it at the end of the document

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization code creates a canvas object that is never attached to any DOM document. The JavaScript snippet doesn't have to be included in line. But you can have a container where you want the canvas to be:

```
<div class="kanye-wrapper">
  <div class="kanye-photo">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/star-clan/images/9/90/Kanye.png">
  </div>
  <div class="kanye-timer" id="timercontainer">

  </div>
  <div class="kanye-link">
    <a href="https://google.com">See why</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="js/kanye.js"></script>
```

Now within your kanye.js, write something like this:

```
document.getElementById('timercontainer').appendChild($r.cvs);
```

Of course this is not portable code. Once you make it work you can externalize the container ID as a parameter.

Comment: The appending happens in his code at line 32 ` $(document.body).append($r.cvs);` the issue is he should create a parameter that is the specific element he wants to append to rather than document.body. Seems op assumes that the location of the script determines where elements get appended to.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Your comment might have located his misunderstanding head-on. Also whether a "document.body" is fully materialized at that stage is highly questionable. It's certainly not DOM-ready.